# Analyze java.io.IOException based on wireshark network sniifer

Tags: java, tcp, wireshark

I have a client that is getting a

```
java.io.IOException: End of message stream
```

The clients wireshark filed the following message, which were all highlighted gray, when the connection threw the exceptions.

The highlight indicates: **tcp.flags & 0x02 || tcp.flags.fin == 1**

```
297 2012-11-30 14:36:49.926004309   10.17.31.1  192.175.217.57  TCP 64  synchronet-db > zymed-zpp [FIN, ACK] Seq=5476 Ack=5648 Win=64688 Len=0

301 2012-11-30 14:36:57.932469330   192.175.217.57  10.17.31.1  TCP 66  pda-gate > synchronet-db [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1380 SACK_PERM=1
302 2012-11-30 14:36:57.932663669   10.17.31.1  192.175.217.57  TCP 66  synchronet-db > pda-gate [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1
305 2012-11-30 14:36:58.277517580   10.17.31.1  192.175.217.57  TCP 64  synchronet-db > pda-gate [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=88 Win=64860 Len=0


309 2012-11-30 14:37:08.276802200   192.175.217.57  10.17.31.1  TCP 66  esnm-zoning > synchronet-db [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1380 SACK_PERM=1
310 2012-11-30 14:37:08.276975480   10.17.31.1  192.175.217.57  TCP 66  synchronet-db > esnm-zoning [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1
313 2012-11-30 14:37:08.594186629   10.17.31.1  192.175.217.57  TCP 64  synchronet-db > esnm-zoning [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=88 Win=64860 Len=0
315 2012-11-30 14:37:08.594592509   192.175.217.57  10.17.31.1  TCP 64  esnm-zoning > synchronet-db [FIN, ACK] Seq=88 Ack=2 Win=65535 Len=0

317 2012-11-30 14:37:18.588553260   192.175.217.57  10.17.31.1  TCP 66  nirp > synchronet-db [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1380 SACK_PERM=1
318 2012-11-30 14:37:18.588744940   10.17.31.1  192.175.217.57  TCP 66  synchronet-db > nirp [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1
321 2012-11-30 14:37:18.906341549   10.17.31.1  192.175.217.57  TCP 64  synchronet-db > nirp [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=88 Win=64860 Len=0
323 2012-11-30 14:37:18.906758749   192.175.217.57  10.17.31.1  TCP 64  nirp > synchronet-db [FIN, ACK] Seq=88 Ack=2 Win=65535 Len=0
```

Any idea what could be causing the exceptions?  Is it just a network problem or could it be a problem with the application?

Comment: It is recurring but it happens sporadically.

Answer (score 2):

The class that threw the exception was expecting more data than it had received when the FIN arrived. It's not a network problem, it's an application protocol problem.

Comment: Can you explain that further?  The application is using java's socket library and is not doing anything special.

Comment: @richs 'End of message stream' is an application message. There is no such message in the JDK. The application is throwing 'new IOException("end of message stream")'.